# Can an outsider that's currently bound by one caster be called and bound by another?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, planes

If a caster knows the true name of an outsider and knows that the outsider is currently bound in service to another caster, is it possible to use *planar binding* or a similar spell to free the outsider from its service?

Alternately, if a caster knows the true name of an outsider that is regularly called by another caster, can the first caster use *planer binding* to cut off the other caster's access to that outsider?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the tour. This is a really interesting question, but I think the site needs to know what kind of power the true name of the outside is giving the caster. If I remember correctly, there are several different competing methods of learning—and outcomes of knowing—an outsider's true name. Can you link to or otherwise point to the system the campaign's using? Thanks for participating and have fun!

Comment: Yes, what @HeyICanChan said. Unless we know if you are going pure-paizo, or some 3PP magic system, or a setting, we cannot give you the answer you need.

Comment: The question regards chiefly Paizo Pathfinder. If no clear ruling exists within that, I would not be opposed to third party answers, as they may shed some light on ways to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

> The target creature is allowed a Will saving throw. If the saving throw succeeds, the creature resists the spell. If the saving throw fails, **the creature is immediately drawn to the trap** (Spell Resistance does not keep it from being called).

The spell *Planar Binding* does not force a creature to do the bidding of the caster; it simply teleports the being into the trap laid for it.

> If the creature does not break free of the trap, you can keep it bound for as long as you dare. **You can attempt to compel the creature** to perform a service by describing the service and perhaps offering some sort of reward. You make a Charisma check opposed by the creature’s Charisma check. The check is assigned a bonus of +0 to +6 based on the nature of the service and the reward. If the creature wins the opposed check, **it refuses service.** New offers, bribes, and the like can be made or the old ones re-offered every 24 hours. This process can be repeated until **the creature promises to serve,** until it breaks free, or until you decide to get rid of it by means of some other spell. Impossible demands or unreasonable commands are never **agreed to.** If you ever roll a natural 1 on the Charisma check, the creature breaks free of the spell’s effect and can escape or attack you.

The bolded language clearly suggests that the extraplanar creature is performing the requested tasks due to the persuasion of the caster, and by free will, not some sort of enchantment magic.  However, given that a roll of a natural 1 enables the creature to escape, it would appear that the persuasion or even the words themselves are enhanced by magic and that the utter failure of speaking that is a natural 1 is enough to disrupt the finely balanced spell.

All of that is to say that there does not appear to be anything stopping the creature from being physically taken from service, as dimensional travel frees creatures from the inward *Magic Circle* spell, of which the spell *Planar Binding* is capable, seeing as the spell is used for calling **extraplanar** creatures.  This means the spell *Planar Binding* could call a bound creature from service and free it (assuming you let it go, or it overpowered you), as long as you know its *proper name*, which is what I assume you meant by *True Name*.

> To discover a single outsider’s true name, **a spellcaster must spend at least a month** in a library or on a quest of discovery to uncover occult mysteries and riddles hidden in the pages of books, scrolls, and glyphs written millennia ago, buried in ancient temples or found among the ravings of madmen’s spellbooks. At the end of this month, **the GM makes a Knowledge (planes) check for the character. The DC is 10 + the creature’s Hit Dice.** The GM can increase the DC by +2, +5, or even +10, based on the power of the outsider or the circumstances of the true name search. A failure by 5 or more turns up false information that may expose researchers to unexpected dangers. For most outer-planar outsiders, knowledge of the creature’s true name is a powerful weapon. In summoning, if the name is spoken correctly (requiring knowledge of at least one of the outsider’s languages, or a Linguistics skill check with a DC equal to 10 + the creature’s Hit Dice), **the target takes a –5 penalty on the Will save to resist being conjured, and if its name is inscribed in the protective magic circle, the outsider takes a –5 penalty on all checks to escape or breach that circle.**

Knowing the creatures *True Name* requires a knowledge (arcana) check with a DC equal to 10 + the creature's HD, extensive study, and only actually gives the creature a -5 to Will saves against resisting the spell and to escape it.

Summary: Yes, the caster *could* both free and "cut off" the outsider from the other caster, as long as he knew the creature's proper name.